# Тень у LinerLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Подскажите как сделать тень у `LinerLayout` сверху как на рисунке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайтe view с background градиентом и положите это view первым. Либо используйте `cardview`

Comment: спасибо, cardview помог.